# How get the last inserted row for an employee's transactions and the last "previous" one with a specific status?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data like:

```
TransId    EmpId     Status    Time
...other employees...
2          3        'action6'  1479166669
3          3        'action2'  1479166670
...other employees...
6          3        'action3'  1479166673
...other employees...
9          3        'action4'  1479166678
...other employees...
14         3        'action5'  1479166685
...other employees...
```

I want to do a MySQL query that gives me the top row (transId = 14) AND the last row for this employee prior to the top row that had the status `'action6'` (transId = 2).

How would I put that in one query? I do not want to use a sub-query if possible.

Comment: You know the employee id beforehand? Or do you want to get the empoyee id from the last row? (Although then there shouldn't be "other employees" after that). What should happen when the last entry would be an `action6`?

Comment: @Solarflare I know the employee ID before hand. Even if the last is the same status, I still want the previous one too

Comment: Can you solve any part of this problem?

Comment: @Strawberry I can solve it 100% with a subquery, but I'd like to avoid that as they're very inefficient

Comment: Subqueries aren't inefficient. Inappropriate indexes are inefficient.

Comment: @Solarflare Because on every row, an additional query is required

Comment: You should post your working "inefficient" subquery solution.

Comment: @DonRhummy No, that is not generally true, and in this case, it is not either. The subquery will be calculated just once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `union` to combine your two rows:

```
(select * from yourtable 
 where EmpId = yourempid 
 order by TransId desc limit 1)
union
(select * from yourtable 
 where EmpId = yourempid 
 and TransId <> (select max(TransId) 
                 from yourtable 
                 where EmpId = yourempid)
 and Status = 'action6'
 order by TransId desc limit 1)
order by TransId;
```

Make sure you have an index for `(EmpId, TransId)`, and optionally additionally `(EmpId, Status, TransId)`.

You should not worry about subqueries. An independent subquery (that doesn't depend on the row) will only get calculated once (and in this case by a single index lookup).

Comment: `TransId < ...` might be faster than `TransId <> ...` (not sure how mysql works with `<>`). Also you need two indexes: `(EmpId, TransId)` and `(EmpId, Status, TransId)` or `(Status, EmpId, TransId)`. `TransId` can be skipped if it is the PK. You can not use `Status` from the `(EmpId, TransId, Status)` index after a range check on `TransId`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes, the 2nd index was wrong, I fixed it, thanks.